# Heat Generation Question

Tags: power-supply

Sorry for my previous vague question. I am setting up a heat generator map for my thermal analysis and I was given that one of the ICs will be dissapating 5.2W. Does this mean that 5.2W of heat will be created into my enclosure? This is my first time setting up a thermal simulation for a pcb so bear with me. In my previous experience if 5.2W was put into something the amount of heat generated was based on the effiency of the item.

Comment: How many kinds of heat are there?  This question is far too vague in it's current form.

Comment: @Nick T well, there is the hot heat and then the cold heat. :-) My guess is he is asking how much heat will be created from it. But still it means nothing to say "5W chip".

Comment: Impossible to say without specific circuit details.

Comment: '5 watts' is the amount of energy per second that's being dissipated by the chip - if your question is really "what TEMPERATURE will it reach?" then you have to look at the thermal characteristics of its package

Comment: @Taniwha not necessarily. '5W Chip' doesn't have to mean the energy per second that is being dissipated. Example, it could be a buck boost that is about to output 5W of power, doesn't mean that chip is dissipating that power.

Comment: In response to comments on the closed question: Your question is bad because it doesn't provide any specifics. What you need to do is to ask a teacher or another student what exactly those 5.2 W are. You are also confusing efficiency and power dissipation. Let's say we have a 5 W device which is 80% efficient. That means that it spends 4 W doing what it's supposed to do and 1 W on all other things, including emitting heat. On the other hand if you have a device which dissipates 5 W as heat, that (probably) means that it converts X watts at Y% efficiency and that 5 W are wasted as heat.

Comment: Next problem is to determine how theoretical solution you want. We can't help you there either because we don't know what type of solution you need, so you need to figure out that part yourself. A real component usually has its junction which generates heat and has thermal resistances to different parts of the case. Your component may have thermal resistance (or conductance) or it may be considered perfect component with zero resistance. That is important because it directly impacts temperature.

Comment: So basically you have resistance between junction and case and resistance between case and air. If component has cooler, then you'd have resistance between junction and case and between case and thermal compound and between thermal compound and cooler and between cooler and air. We can't tell if those thing will make an impact on your assignment or not, so we can't help you there.

Comment: To cut the long story short, your question assumes that we know how you do such problems in your school. We don't, so you could provide us with similar solved problem or more information so that we could determine what you are expected to do. Then we may give you ideas on how to do it. In question such as this one, hard part is often in understanding what is being asked and finding the list of things which can be disregarded.

Answer (score 3):

If you're given that 5 W is being *dissipated* by a component, than that strongly implies that it will be burning that as heat.  Other components around it will likely also be dissipating some heat as well, but you make it sound like this is some idealized academic question for you learning some thermal sim (FEA?) package.

For the parts that I've mostly dealt with—discrete MOSFETs—the "power rating" is usually given as a current rating under some conditions (easily convertible into watts), and it varies wildly depending on the thermal resistance from the junction (T<sub>J</sub>, all that really matters) to ambient (T<sub>A</sub>).  A free standing part with no heat sinking may have several or dozens of times the thermal resistance compared with even modest heatsinks.  Additionally, the figure might be quoted at T<sub>A</sub> = 25 °C, not the actual maximum temperature your system will operate at, so even if you have a part that *can* dissipate 5 W, there might be some caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the efficiency has already been taken into account, if you are given a dissipation figure, so you can't use the efficiency factor again. Maybe there is 6W going in, and 0.8W coming out, so 5.2W is dissipated. (In this case efficiency was 0.8/6 = 13%). You couldn't use the 13% again, on top of the 5.2W.